# How put a vertical label on a page

Tags: html

I have an table ana title on that table, but I want to put also a label on the left side of the table but vertically, how can I do that??

That's my table code so far

```
<div class="ibox-content">
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;" colspan="29">DESTINO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let val of table_headers">{{val}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let val of array; let i = index">
            <td *ngFor="let item of val; let j = index" [class.coloured]="i === j">{{item}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a single cell that spans across all your rows. Use CSS to rotate it.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let val of array; let i = index">
    <td *ngIf="i === 0" [rowSpan]="array.length" class="vertical-label">vertical</td>
    <td *ngFor="let item of val; let j = index" [class.coloured]="i === j">{{item}}</td>
</tr>
```

```css
.vertical-label {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```